# How to call a function on the BuildContext of the route underneath the current one?

Tags: flutter, routes

I should clarify this question by an example.

I have a button that has to pop the current route and change tab in the route bellow.
So basically I want to have an onPressed function like this (I use the AutoRoute package):

```
() {
  context.popRoute();
  context.router.navigate(const SearchRoute()); // uses wrong context
}
```

But obviously this doesn't work because the context used to change the tab isn't the correct one. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `AutoTabsRouter` for your tabs, then this should work.

```
final autoTabsRouter = AutoTabsRouter.of(context);

context.popRoute();
autoTabsRouter.navigate(TabTwoRoute());
```

Let me know if it doesn't. Happy coding:)